# Wep-Page that uses smart URLs within WordPress Installation directory

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, slug

Web-Server-Environment: nginx

I've got a WordPress installation that uses smart URLs / nice page slugs (so for example news may be accessed by "http://my-wp-installation.de/news/new-loaction-in-berlin-germany" instead of ".../posts.php?id=xyz").

I've created a small sub-Website (it's too specifiy to solve my purpos within wordpress its self) using a small framework that (due the framework) also uses smart URLs (rewritten by the nginx). So when my page is installed standalone I can access sites of my webpage by "http://mystandalonewebsite.de/about/our-team" for example)

The sub-Website now needs to be accessed by the same domain as the WordPress installation. So I copied the sub-Website into the root folder of the WP installation. This works fine as long as the query string is flat and does not contain a multi level path. So "http://my-wp-installation.de/mystandalonewebsite" works. But as soon as I try to access "http://my-wp-installation.de/mystandalonewebsite/about/our-team" its wordpress to respond the request and telling me (of course) that the page does not exist because the first rule to hit by the rewrite engine is the wordpress rule. The request nerver reaches my sub-Website.

How can I fix this? In this case subdomains are no option. I really NEED to access my page this way: "http://my-wp-installation.de/mystandalonewebsite/about/our-team"